# Jsfiddle with external libs, Font Awesome not rendering, isotope does not toggle layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope, jsfiddle

Jslint says everything is fine, and I am able to add the external libs. Also *code works fine in the IDE/browser, not in Jsfiddle*

**using Jsfiddle I am trying to debug Isotope toggle size** and layout in JS fiddle, but I am unable to get the external libs to render.

Can you help, and correct me?
  -   if the issue is the order of libs, or what options I selected, is it the semi-colon infront of the JS, I thought this is normally good/safe coding in JS..

[Here is the code in JsFiddle, it works in the IDE not JsFiddle](http://bit.ly/1KN7LlL)

I am using the following font awesome, bootstrap, isotope, ba-bounce, jquery 1.11.2 (JSfiddle only shows 1.11.0)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too localized as it's related to configuring a third party tool (jsfiddle) and not programming specific.

Comment: @War10ck there are 68 pages worth of questions tagged `jsfiddle`.  It's a tool that helps users communicate the problems they are having in order to ask better questions here on SO.  I think we can help new users figure out how to leverage it.  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you were trying to load your resources from, but you need to provide a URL to the `css` or `js` file you want to include.  These are usually easy to find hosted on a cdn. I have reconstructed your fiddle using cdn links to the external resources:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/voveson/popzfey4/5/

Comment: appreciate the answer and help!  I was adding the `js/css` libs via _External Resources options/box_ I also see your fiddle looks exactly like mine with onLoad i.e. no head, so I'm wondering what you did differently, or what did you fix in my fiddle. Can you share what you did to get it working please.

Comment: Yes, the *external resources* option is what you want. What had you entered there?  I fixed the fiddle by searching for `cdn` URLs to the resources you needed an replacing them in the external resources section.  For example, search online for "bootstrap cdn" and you'll likely be directed to www.bootstrapcdn.com where you can copy URLs for the bootstrap `js` and `css`.  Glad I could help!

Comment: So you search and copied a full URL!   I was using only the _lib_ name and jsFiddle was resolving the path, I saw help page on the net to do it that way, glad this worked.